# How do I get list item when I click on classic report icon

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I've classics report of all the events, what I need is to show list of attendees as popup when clicked on link.

(https://photos.app.goo.gl/bfa3imFndJfPyepq7)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Apex is capable of doing that natively.

What you could do, is to create a link which would open a modal window (maybe the closest thing to a popup LoV) and display those values.

Alternatively, if there aren't that many values you have to display, you could use `listagg` and display them as the interactive report column values (for example, comma-separated). For example:

```
SQL> select e.deptno,
  2         d.dname,
  3         listagg(e.ename, ', ') within group (order by e.ename) names
  4  from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  5  where d.deptno = 10
  6  group by e.deptno, d.dname;

    DEPTNO DNAME          NAMES
---------- -------------- ----------------------------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     CLARK, KING, MILLER

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but couldn't let it stand this way.

I may be missing something in the requirements here I think Apex easily capable of doing that.

The icon just a column in your report of the type Link that will open another page, which happens to be a modal window. Your icon just needs to pass the event ID to your modal window, which display a report that lists the attendees for that event.

Like this: [image]

Formatting your detail window to not contain all the headings that the browser usually includes will be the trickiest part, but that formatting is left to the reader. ;-)